# Sample PHP or JS code to reveal content on FaceBook Like

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

I'm looking for some sample code PHP (or JavaScript) to reveal content on a HTML page (outside of Facebook) after detecting a Facebook Like event.

I see that it should be looking for edge.create:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

Anyone have working code for this they can share?

Answer (score 3):

They have an example right on that link you supplied...is that not what you had in mind?:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
    function(response) {
        //do whatever you want here
        document.getElementById('previouslyHiddenContent').style.display='block';
    }
);
```

ah, you may also want to write a cookie for subsequent visits

to Nick's point, maybe you'd want to fire an AJAX call instead of literally revealing content...just to make it one step removed (and, if that content were large, would shorten page load)

Comment: +1. This technique is really flaky though. It's slow and you need a backup plan for people who are already fans (their button will be grey, they will have to unlike and like again unles you give them another way). If possible, get people to accept an fb app and use the API to see if they liked something or not.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is a much better way to do this since it's server side and the client has no control over it (unlike using JS to show a div, which people can simply just set the div to be visible through editing the DOM, and so see the page content you are trying to keep hidden).

Something like this is better.

```
<?php
include 'facebook.php'; // facebook php sdk

$app_id = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$app_secret = "YYYYYYYYYYYYYY";
$facebook = new Facebook (array(
'appId' => $app_id,
'secret' => $app_secret,
'cookie' => true
));

$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();

$page_id = $signed_request["page"]["id"];
$page_admin = $signed_request["page"]["admin"];
$like_status = $signed_request["page"]["liked"];
$country = $signed_request["user"]["country"];
$locale = $signed_request["user"]["locale"];
if ($like_status) {
  // display whatever you want to show the person who has liked the page
} else {
  // display what you want to show people who haven't liked the page
}
?>
```

Comment: That work only on a Facebook Page. AMcDermott is outside of Facebook.

Comment: & this is also can be edited from client side through cookie manipulation ;)